# I want to have the option to quit or accept specific range of values

Tags: python-3.x, user-input, boolean-expression

```
q = input ("enter(1-51) or (q to quit):")
while q != 'q' and int (q) < 1 or int (q) > 51:
    q = input ("enter(1-51) or (q to quit):")
```

and I get the below error, also I tried to use `str()` around the variable also got the same error, also advise me how can I perform a technique of exiting a game or round in a game using something similar to the above if it is not the best way.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'q'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

really easy fix: add brackets:

```
q = input ("enter(1-51) or (q to quit):")
while q != 'q' and (int (q) < 1 or int (q) > 51):
  #  brackets here ^                and here   ^
    q = input ("enter(1-51) or (q to quit):")
```

Without brackets it will always try `or int (q) > 51` if the first conditional is False. (so when `q == 'q'`)  However with the brackets it will not evaluate any further when `q == 'q'` so you don't have to worry about raising an error.  On the other hand you are still not protected from other invalid input:

```
enter(1-51) or (q to quit):hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Tadhg/Documents/codes/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    while q != 'q' and (int (q) < 1 or int (q) > 51):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hello'
```

so you could also add another check before the `int` conversion to make sure that all the characters are digits (`.isdigit()`) as well:

```
while q !='q' and not (q.isdigit() and 1<=int(q)<=51):
```

Comment: thanks,q = input ("enter(1-51) or (q to quit):")
 while q != 'q' and (q.isdigit () and (int (q) < 1 or int (q) > 51)):
  q = input ("enter(1-51) or (q to quit):")

Comment: that still doesn't have the correct logic, when `q.isdigit()` is False (as in not a valid number) the while loop breaks!

Comment: you would need to change `not (q.isdigit() and` to be `(not q.isdigit () or`

Comment: so the final one would be `q = input ("enter(1-51) or (q to quit):") ;
while q != 'q' and (not q.isdigit () or (int (q) < 1 or int (q) > 51)):
    q = input ("enter(1-51) or (q to quit):") `

Comment: thanks, yes your brackets solved the problem but you raised a new question of how to protect from other inputs, anyway I rewrote your above code to suit my requirements which is prompt me if I Do not enter 'q' or I enter number less than 1 or more than 51..similar to..                              **q = input ("enter(1-51) or (q to quit):")
 while q != 'q' and (q.isdigit () and (int (q) < 1 or int (q) > 51)):
  q = input ("enter(1-51) or (q to quit):")**

Comment: exactly, that solved it. Sorry I was trying to go to a new line and it submitted the text. Here is the last code..                                                                      **q = input ("enter(1-51) or (q to quit):")
 while q != 'q' and (not q.isdigit () or ((int (q) < 1 or int (q) > 51))):
  q = input ("enter(1-51) or (q to quit):")**

Comment: so, in the same context usually in the games you will have the option to pause the game by pressing ESC anytime, can I implement this in my code as it seems that it uses different thread for pausing the program/game sequence!

Comment: If you are using `input` I'd assume you are making your game in the terminal, which would mean that it is paused every time you wait for some input... What is this about "different threads for pausing"?

Comment: logically you are right, as it is in the text mode, I meant also instead of putting the quit option with every step of dealing the cards, playing specific card or shuffling as it will look unwelcoming to say in every step "are you willing to quit the game"!

Answer (score 0):

Your program is almost correct. Here is the fix:

```
while q != 'q' and (int (q) < 1 or int (q) > 51):
```

---

Normally, `and` has higher precedence than `or`. So your original code would have been interpreted as:

```
while (q != 'q' and int (q) < 1) or int (q) > 51:
```

But this interpretation leads to faulty behavior. Because if `q == 'q'`, then the `!=` is false, the `and` clause is false, so the third clause after the `or` gets evaluated. This causes `int(q)` to be evaluated, which causes the exception.

Comment: thanks Nayuki, it corrected my problem, also today I learned that and gets evaluated before the or (y
)

Comment: makes sense, as AND is multiplication while OR is addition